# how to get accurate time of day instead DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get the accurate current time in the following format:
HH:MM:SS:mmm

HH - hours

MM - minutes

SS - seconds

mmm - miliseconds

As far as I know DateTime.Now is not accurate enough and StopWatch is just for measuring time.
I want to get accuracy of 1 milisecond.

Comment: Define "accurate" and explain your use case.

Comment: When you use `timeBeginPeriod` you can get `DateTime.Now` to have 1ms accuracy(depending on how you define accuracy). But it probably won't be within one 1ms of the correct time.

Comment: accurate is a timestamp with precision of 3 digits in miliseconds.

Comment: Do you need a timestamp that's synchronized with the global time to 1ms, or just something that gives you three digits and is (mostly) consistent within on a single computer?

Comment: a timestamp that's synchronized with the global time.

Comment: Think this through. Suppose you *did* have a clock in your machine that was both precise and accurate to the millisecond. Now suppose you call a method to get the current time, into a register, and then you copy the register into a local variable. What happens if the CPU switches the thread context between the time the value is *fetched into a register* and the time that the register is *copied to the local variable*? By the time your process gets control back again, 16 milliseconds have gone by and the timing data is now *wrong* by 16 milliseconds.

Comment: In short: a clock only tells you *what time it was*; it never tells you *what time it is* because *arbitrarily much time might have passed between when you made a copy of the clock data, and when you use the copy.* That is why DateTime.Now is only accurate to about 16 milliseconds: *because that's about how often threads context switch*. Any *more* accuracy would be a lie. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx for more thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have here is that DateTime gives you a very precise time result, but it's accuracy is governed by both the systems hardware clock and how quickly the OS responds to the time request.

Precision and accuracy may seem like the same thing, but they're not. You may be able to write a measurement down to 1 billionth of a metre, but if your measuring device is 1 metre long without graduations then you only have an accuracy of 1 metre.

If you really need an accurate time down to 1 millisecond then you'll need another time source that you can poll directly thus bypassing any OS delays.

It is possible to get devices that allow connection to a realtime clock, for example gps receivers (which are highly accurate). Again accuracy between two receivers will depend on whether they are the same distance from the satellite or not.

Comment: there are two other sources of accurate time in modern PC. the HPET and the RDTC. They don't rely on kernel ticks. and kernel tick reads the HPET anyway since the end of the 90's (before it was reading the RTC if I'm not mistaken).  RDTC is the timer used by QueryPerformanceCounter (most of the time because it actually depends on ACPI). And it is a register in the CPU, so nanosecond is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [resolution of `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) actually goes down to 100 nanosecond resolution (even though the resolution may be limited to less by the implementation), millisecond resolution should not be a problem.

All properties you need to solve your problem are available in the normal [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties.aspx) type.

Edit: As @CodeInChaos points out, even millisecond resolution is not guaranteed using this API, so if you actually need that resolution, it's no good :-/

Comment: 1ms accuracy is a problem. The windows APIs behind `DateTime.Now` only work with the accuracy of the system timer, which can vary between 1ms and 16ms. It doesn't matter that `DateTime` can represent 100ns, if you have no clock that gives you such values.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Very interesting, I did not know that. Could you point me to more info?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx "The resolution of this property depends on the system timer." And the system timer can be influenced by `timeBeginPeriod`

Comment: In practice ~5ms is the actual boundary that I have experienced (and suffered from) on some server boards you can find more accurate clocks though, but it will cost you.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now has a resolution of 10ms 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx

what accurate resolution will be appropriate for you?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Multimedia Timer timeGetTime()

Granularity: 1 millisecond
Precision: 1 millisecond
Apparent precision: 2.32804262366679e-006 seconds
Apparent jitter: 1.19727906360006e-007 seconds

Ripped from [here](http://www.bytefusion.com/products/ntm/ptnt/highresolutiontime.htm)

Comment: only if you have set the global (system wide) kernel tick to be 1ms before. and it is the minimal limit, default is 15ms, and for good reasons. CPU wake ups, heavy useless interrupt payload...